# Cognitive science/brain sciences and their impact on philosophy of mathematics

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, psychology

How does/did cognitive science influence philosophy of mathematics? I saw somewhere (Wikipedia, "Cognitive science") that it helped to create new perspective on philosophy of mathematics, but it did not mention how it influenced.

Answer (score 2):

Following the Wikipedia page on [Philosophy of Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics) (linked from the article you cited) would lead you to the Embodied Mind theory, and further, to the canonical explication of this theory in George Lakoff's [*Where Mathematics Comes From*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Mathematics_Comes_From).

For future reference: if an uncited claim in Wikipedia includes a link, follow the link-- the citation may be on the other side.